# Naming conventions for type tables: to use a 'Type' suffix or not

Tags: sql

Is there a benefit to naming a type table (lookup table) with `Type` as a suffix?

In my database right now, it goes both ways, and I would like to come up with a naming standard on this.

**Pros:**

- It easily identifies the table as a type table which typically have similar structures and functions.

**Cons:**

- It makes the name slightly longer and the FK ends up being longer as well.

Am I missing anything?

**For example:**

```
StatusType(id int, code varchar(10), name varchar(10), description varchar(25)
```

or just:

```
Status(id int, code varchar(10), name varchar(10), description varchar(25)
```

Comment: What is a "type table"?  Do you have an example?

Comment: Example Added to make question more clear.

Comment: The important thing about naming conventions is to be consistent. I don't see any clear winner here so I guess go with what makes more sense to you. BTW, this question is off-topic here since the answer will probably be opinion based.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response - that was more helpful than just voting to close without an explanation.

Comment: Assuming I've correctly understood the purpose of what you described as a *'Type Table'*, I have witnessed the use of the term `valid` used in some databases as a naming convention for tables which essentially store a list of available keys referenced as foreign keys in other tables. For your example, this might be: `valid_status` the term `valid` here is implying that this table contains a list of the *valid* identifiers which may be referenced by the foreign keys in other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define the table as:

```
create table Statuses (
    statusId int,
    code varchar(10),
    name varchar(10),
    description varchar(25)
);
```

Why?

- "status" is an entity.  I name tables (generally) in the plural of the entity.  Plurals are handy for two reasons.  First, the table contains multiple instances, so plural makes sense.  Second, plurals are less likely to conflict with SQL keywords/reserved words.
- The identity is `statusId` or `status_id`.  That is, the entity name followed by "id".  Most references would use the same name.  This makes joins obvious.
- I see no reason to separate this as a "different" type of entity from other entities.  If I did, I would use a prefix.  For instance, I might use the `cust` prefix for entities specifically about customers.

Comment: Ok, I get your point here: if you have a `customer` table, then it makes sense to have a 'customer_type' table,  But there is no `status` table, so it doesn't really make sense to have a `status_type` table